# Why Django think OR is complex?

Tags: python, sql, django

I read some model operation from Django's document, and find  [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q)

[image]

I'm curious that OR in WHERE is just basic concept, why Django think it's a complex query?

Comment: It's not saying that OR is complex, it's saying that an OR is more complex than a simple AND

Comment: You should always post text as text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, what's "more complex" here is the full query syntax, whatever the logical operator. The full syntax for an "AND" query is

```
MyModel.objects.filter(Q(foo="bar") & Q(quux="baaz"))
```

but since in practice you more often use AND queries than OR queries, the ORM provides a shortcut for AND queries:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(foo="bar", quux="baaz")
```

Comment: You will be sung, Bruno

Comment: @KenNieh at last !-)

Answer (score 1):

Because `.filter(Q(x=foo) | Q(y=baz))` is objectively more complex syntax compared to `.filter(x=foo)`, that's all.

Comment: I dont think its referring to syntax, its suggesting that you might need to filter on something more extravagant than `foo AND bar`